# Defined a new variable, broken with quotation marks

Tags: powershell

my new defination is

```
$var="Tony said:"I like this game!""
```

It appeared that only

```
"Tony said:"
```

part can be recoginized, but I need the whole sentence. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

A simple solution is to just double the quotes.  See the link for other options.

```
$var="Tony said:""I like this game!"""
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completness, alternative solutions are to use the escape character:

```
$var= "Tony said:\`"I like this game!\`""
```

or "[here strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx)" which are normally useful for multi-line texts but can be used for this case as well:

```
$var=@"
Tony said:"I like this game!"
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier: single quotes. You can put any number of double quotes in a single-quote string, or vice versa:

```
 $var = 'Tony said, "I like this game!"'
```

or

```
 $var = "Tony said, 'I like this game!'"
```

I personally think this is the easiest and most readable solution.

Comment: Worth noting that variables within single quotes will not be evaluated.

Comment: Good point. That's the fundamental difference between single and double quotes -- single quotes will treat all internal text literally, whereas double quotes will expand variables [or expressions enclosed in $()].